# Django Admin: вставка изображений с подписями в текст статьи при помощи custom tag

Tags: django, django-admin

Требуется инструмент для добавления иллюстраций с подписями в текст статьи.

Модели для статьи и для иллюстраций:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    text = models.TextField()

class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to = 'static/images/', max_length=300)
    img_alt = models.CharField(max_length=550, blank = True)
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы работало так: в тексте статьи ставим курсор в то место, куда нужно добавить блок иллюстрации. Кликаем по специальной иконке или кнопке -- открывается окно для создания блока: в нем выбор картинки (ImageModel), поле для подписи, выбор выравнивания (center, right, left). Вносим данные, сохраняем -- в текст вставляется custom tag, примерно так:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<IMG_BLOCK img_id="545" img_caption="Некая подпись к картинке" img_align="center"/>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<IMG_BLOCK img_id="148" img_caption="Подпись ко второй картинке" img_align="right"/>

<p>Paragraph 3.</p>

<...>
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Взять WYSIWYG-редактор, типа [CKEditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor), и написать для него плагин или  использовать [готовый](https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-filer/).

Comment: Спасибо! А как (в общих чертах) в своем плагине получить id выбранного изображения?